# Lvalue required as left operand of asignment error

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

This has been answered by other people but I can't figure out how to apply it to my code because, frankly, it's too simple.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int pythagorean () 
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    cout << "A: ";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "B; ";
    cin >> b;
    a*=a;
    b*=b;
    a+b=c; //This is where I get the error. Any ideas?
    cout << c;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to set `c`, so it has to be

```
c = a+b;
```

`a+b` is an expression, not a variable you can assign to.

Answer (score 0):

There the left hand side is `a+b` which is not an assignable variable (lvalue).